# Breaking up conditionals in order to reduce DRAM usage

Tags: c, memory, embedded, firmware

I work in firmware and came across this piece of code (obfuscated key words for privacy reasons). I find this kind of hard to believe, but we are working with a fairly old compiler.

```
// For optimization purposes, the following "if" statements are broken up as opposed to
// being AND'ed together to ensure the compiler accesses the DRAM as little as possible.
if (searchFooNum == p_entry->fooNum)
{
    Foo_t const fooStart = p_entry->fooOffset;

    // Check if this entry contains any FOOs of interest.
    if (fooStart <= lastFooOffset)
    {
        FooOffset_t const entryLastFoo = fooStart + ConvertBarCountToFooCount(p_entry->barCount) - 1;

        if (p_searchInfo->fooZoneOffset <= entryLastFoo)
        {
            FooOffset_t const fooOffset = (p_searchInfo->fooZoneOffset > entryStartFoo) ? (p_searchInfo->fooZoneOffset - entryStartFoo): 0;
            QuxZoneMapping_t*       p_QuxZoneMapping;

            if ( isFullZoneMapping )
            {
                FooOffset_t const curFooOffset = p_entry->zoneOffset + fooOffset;

                if (p_searchInfo->bazIndexMappingTable == TRUE)
                {
                    p_LbaZoneMapping = GetPointerToBazIndexZoneMapping( p_searchInfo, curFooOffset );
                }
            ...
```

In other words, how would nesting if statements reduce dram usage? AFAIK functions will allocate a set amount stack for the function to execute?

Comment: It might have been specific to a particular compiler, maybe it allocated stack space for each block as it entered it, rather than allocating the maximum stack space needed at function entry.

Comment: Also, it's not clear how you would AND these together, since the inner conditions make use of variables that are assigned after an outer test succeeds.

Comment: You can do it, but it would get extremely verbose because you don't have the temporary variables: `if (searchFooNum == p_entry->fooNum && p_entry->fooOffset < lastFooOffset && p_searchinfo->fooZoneOffset < p_entry->fooOffset + ConvertBarCountToFooCount(p_entry->barCount) - 1 ...)`

Comment: It could also be as simple as the coder at the time did not fully understand _what or how_ DRAM is used.  I have seen people go into well documented source code and remove all the comments to increase run-time speed.

Comment: Perhaps the author of the comment did not understand that C's `&&` operator performs short-circuit evaluation.  Or perhaps the targeted C compiler actually *didn't* short-circuit, though I would account that pretty broken.

Comment: `with a fairly old compiler` Would you mind specifying what compiler is that exactly?

Comment: @KamilCuk it was GCC 3.4.5 targeting ARM cortex M4

Comment: Wut? gcc3.4.5 is from like 2005, cortexM4 is from 2010 ? porting I guess : )

Answer (score 1):

None of the known by me implementations (compilers) do it this way. All of them calculate the total usage of the stack in the function and allocate it acordingly. I believe it is because otherwise it will make advanced code optimizations difficult or even impossible (when the compiler aggressively optimize the code, the order of execution does not have to be the sane as in your C code - only the observable behaviour has to be the same)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the comments are misleading. More likely, the optimization is to use local variables, e.g.:

```
Foo_t const fooStart = p_entry->fooOffset;

if (fooStart <= lastFooOffset)
{
    FooOffset_t const entryLastFoo = fooStart + ConvertBarCountToFooCount(p_entry->barCount) - 1;

    if (p_searchInfo->fooZoneOffset <= entryLastFoo)
    {
```

instead of:

```
if (p_entry->fooOffset <= lastFooOffset)
{
    if (p_searchInfo->fooZoneOffset <= p_entry->fooOffset + ConvertBarCountToFooCount(p_entry->barCount) - 1)
    {
```

which could be *AND'ed together* to:

```
if (p_entry->fooOffset <= lastFooOffset
        && p_searchInfo->fooZoneOffset <= p_entry->fooOffset + ConvertBarCountToFooCount(p_entry->barCount) - 1)
{
```

Using local variables to prevent repeated access to the same memory can indeed speed up the code. Even a good C/C++ compiler usually cannot optimize this automatically due to a C/C++ specific problem called *pointer aliasing*.

Answer (score 0):

> it was GCC 3.4.5 targeting ARM cortex M4

> how would nesting if statements reduce dram usage?

It wouldn't, it's unrelated. Optimizations kicks in and the code doesn't really matter that much - what matters is what the code represents.

> functions will allocate a set amount stack for the function to execute?

That of course depends on your compiler. But yer. Because your compiler is smart, it will optimize multiple push-stack-pointer-instructions within one function to a single one on top of the function.